# Download UNPKG React zip

Tags: reactjs

I could create a react app like this simply and it worked.

`index.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.13.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.3/babel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(<div>Hello World</div>, document.getElementById('root'))
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, because i can't code online all the time. i wanna download those files with their root file with `.zip`. Where can i download them? Why i`m unsure just to download that links itself because i think they may have other dependencies too.

Thanks!

Comment: not sure I fully understand your question, but those are URL like any other, you can simply paste them in the address bar and then save or even copy&paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpkg is a global content delivery network for everything on npm, you can just copy and paste their links into your script tags.

Though if you want to have all your files locally, you can use npm for it.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dom